# Having Troubles Installing Ninja on Gentoo

Tags: software-installation, vim, gentoo, emerge

I am trying to install ninja (as a prequisite for YouCompleteMe for vim) and I get error. Here is the summary of my `=dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo`

```
    Portage 2.3.31 (python 3.5.5-final-0, default/linux/amd64/17.0/no-multilib/prefix/kernel-2.6.32+, gcc-7.3.0, glibc-2.25-r11, 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64)
=================================================================
                         System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64-x86_64-Intel-R-_Xeon-R-_CPU_E5-2630_v3_@_2.40GHz-with-centos-6.6-Final
KiB Mem:   132052796 total,  24015248 free
KiB Swap:    8388604 total,    935832 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Thu, 19 Apr 2018 06:00:01 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: 9cc1a3f648766c962e7a465020db4820b6ba6e01
sh bash 4.4_p19
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.30 p1) 2.30.0
app-shells/bash:          4.4_p19::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:            5.26.1-r2::gentoo
dev-lang/python:          2.7.14-r1::gentoo, 3.5.5::gentoo
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.29.2::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.4.1-r2::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.13::gentoo
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.69-r4::gentoo
sys-devel/automake:       1.16.1-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:       2.30-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:            7.3.0-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.9.1::gentoo
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.6-r5::gentoo
sys-devel/make:           4.2.1-r3::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 4.16-r1::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.25-r11::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /home/******/gentoo/usr/portage
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage
    priority: -1000
    sync-rsync-verify-jobs: 1
    sync-rsync-verify-max-age: 24
    sync-rsync-verify-metamanifest: yes
    sync-rsync-extra-opts: 

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64 ~amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/gconf /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo /home/*****/gentoo/etc/gentoo-release"
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/home/******/gentoo/usr/portage/distfiles"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles force-prefix merge-sync multilib-strict news parallel-fetch preserve-libs protect-owned sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans unprivileged"
FFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://distfiles.gentoo.org"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="-j8"
PKGDIR="/home/*****/gentoo/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/home/******/gentoo/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/home/******/gentoo/var/tmp"
USE="acl amd64 berkdb bzip2 cli crypt cxx dri fortran gdbm iconv ipv6 modules ncurses nls nptl openmp pcre prefix readline seccomp ssl tcpd unicode zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="karbon plan sheets stage words" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock isync itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput keyboard mouse" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-6 php7-0" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres9_5" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_5" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby22 ruby23" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="amdgpu fbdev intel nouveau radeon radeonsi vesa dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CC, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, ENV_UNSET, INSTALL_MASK, LANG, LC_ALL, LINGUAS, PORTAGE_BINHOST, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS
```

and here is the output of emerege for vim-app/youcompleteme:

```
 * IMPORTANT: 11 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


 * IMPORTANT: 3 config files in '/home/******/gentoo/etc/portage' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES and CONFIGURATION FILES UPDATE TOOLS
 * sections of the emerge man page to learn how to update config files.
Calculating dependencies... done!

>>> Verifying ebuild manifests
>>> Running pre-merge checks for sys-libs/libomp-6.0.0
 * Determining the location of the kernel source code
 * Unable to find kernel sources at /usr/src/linux
 * Please make sure that /usr/src/linux points at your running kernel, 
 * (or the kernel you wish to build against).
 * Alternatively, set the KERNEL_DIR environment variable to the kernel sources location
 * Unable to calculate Linux Kernel version for build, attempting to use running version
 * Found kernel object directory:
 *     /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
 * Found sources for kernel version:
 *     2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
>>> Running pre-merge checks for sys-libs/compiler-rt-6.0.0
>>> Running pre-merge checks for sys-libs/compiler-rt-sanitizers-6.0.0

>>> Emerging (1 of 15) dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo
 * ninja-1.8.2.tar.gz BLAKE2B SHA512 size ;-) ...                                                                                            [ ok ]
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking ninja-1.8.2.tar.gz to /home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work
>>> Source unpacked in /home/*******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work
>>> Preparing source in /home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2 ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /home/*****/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2 ...
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2 ...
bootstrapping ninja...
"./src/inline.sh" kBrowsePy < ./src/browse.py > build/browse_py.h
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -MMD -MT build/browse.o -MF build/browse.o.d -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fvisibility=hidden -pipe '-DNINJA_PYTHON="python3.5"' -O2 -DNDEBUG -fdiagnostics-color -DUSE_PPOLL -DNINJA_HAVE_BROWSE -I. -O2 -pipe -O2 -pipe -c ./src/browse.cc -o build/browse.o
re2c: /home/******/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by re2c)
re2c: /home/*******/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by re2c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 466, in <module>
    if has_re2c():
  File "configure.py", line 463, in has_re2c
    return int(proc.communicate()[0], 10) >= 1103
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''
 * ERROR: dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   (no error message)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line 124:  Called src_compile
 *   environment, line 2139:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       run_for_build "${PYTHON}" configure.py --bootstrap --verbose || die;
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2'
 * S: '/home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2'

>>> Failed to emerge dev-util/ninja-1.8.2, Log file:

>>>  '/home/*******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/temp/build.log'

 * Messages for package sys-libs/libomp-6.0.0:

 * Unable to find kernel sources at /usr/src/linux
 * Unable to calculate Linux Kernel version for build, attempting to use running version

 * Messages for package dev-util/ninja-1.8.2:

 * ERROR: dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   (no error message)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line 124:  Called src_compile
 *   environment, line 2139:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       run_for_build "${PYTHON}" configure.py --bootstrap --verbose || die;
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-util/ninja-1.8.2::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/home/********/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/home/******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/home/*******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2'
 * S: '/home/*******/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/ninja-1.8.2/work/ninja-1.8.2'
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The version for my GCC:
`[1] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-7.3.0 *`

Comment: More helpful would be the output of the `emerge` command.

Answer (score 2):

### Observation 1

Why are you storing your portage tree in your home directory??  *Don't worry, after writing Observation 2, I understand why*. Seeing that makes me cringe.  The default location should be: `/usr/portage`.  That location helps when creating local overlays(`usr/local/portage` differentiates a local tree from the one you sync), i.e. packages with custom version numbers, or those packages that don't exist in the main portage tree.  It's generally accepted that the tree and/or overlays on a Gentoo system are a system component, and therefore should be in a system directory.  Portage features are controlled with and by files residing in `/etc/portage`.  See the [Gentoo Portage Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage). Your home directory should be used for things you download or create. This creates a boundary between the system and the user.  **That boundary is the foundation for any *NIX system**.

### Observation 2

Although your GCC compiler is currently unstable, that is not the cause of your problem.  See [Gentoo Package - sys-devel/gcc](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-devel/gcc).  The issue is the version of [sys-libs/glibc](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-libs/glibc).  Portage believes you have version 2.25-r11, but your host system(hence the reason for Observation 1. As a hunch, I believe your install is inside a system running another version or distribution of linux) contains and is linked against version 3.4.20.  Portage gathers the Linking information from the host because it believes that your host system is the system it's installed on all by itself, as a running system.  Refer to Observation #1.

See [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host).  In short, you have a few options:

1. Point Portage to the Right Environment variables, using Method 1 described in the question I linked, or
2. Delete your install from your home directory, and [Follow the Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64)(arch is irrelevant), and omit the Setting up the bootloader chapter, along with Finalizing the Installation.  Always use the `chroot` command to enter the environment. Create a user in the chroot, and `su user` every time you enter the chroot.

   **Tip: Create /home/username/mnt/gentoo**

then use the Chrooting procedure outlined in [Gentoo Handbook: Chrooting](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base#Chrooting), pointing the chroot to `/home/username/mnt/gentoo`.  After chroot, observation 1's boundary is created.  This will fool portage into believing it's installed on a host of it's own, because it honors the chroot environment.

3. Use this script: [Install GNU libc version parallel to existing system](https://gist.github.com/cheuerde/7229f304856e59ce183a), to simplify Option 1, although I would advise against it if you share your host with other users, because if you set the `--prefix` option to somewhere in your home directory, and then share your programs with those other users, it will not run.

Comment: for observation 1: maybe a prefix installation...?